# Sorting Visuals in a Embedded Power BI Report

Tags: sorting, powerbi-embedded

I want to to sort visuals within a Report in Embedded Power BI sing Jquery. As a workaround, I tried to add a unique id to the Visuals' tag  thinking that I will be able to sort the Visuals later based on their Ids. As a result, I tried to penetrate through the # document inside the  as below.

```
$("iframe").each(function () {
                var ifrm = $(this);

                var win = ifrm.contentWindow;
                var doc = ifrm.contentDocument ? ifrm.contentDocument :
                    ifrm.contentWindow.document;
               });
```

However, I am getting win as undefined due to which not able to access the tag elements inside the #document.

Could anyone please suggest if we can able to access this #document and manipulate the Visuals' order.
Or is there any other method to sort the Visuals within a report in Embedded Power BI using javascript/jquery.
I have tried various combination of Jquery methods to access the class inside this Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the elements inside the report (iframe) using jQuery/JavaScript.

Normally visuals appear in the report in the order they were added using Power BI Desktop or Service. If you want your visuals to appear in sorted order, you have to make another page and add visuals in your desired order and then make that page as active page when required.

Please follow the below code snippets to set your required page as active:

1. Get a reference to the `HTML` element that contains the embedded report:

   ```js
   const embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
   ```
2. Embed the `report`:

   ```js
   const report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfig);
   ```
3. Get the list of pages:

   ```js
   const pages = await report.getPages();
   const pageNumber = 2 /// Your required page number
   ```
4. Set the required page as active: ​

   ```js
   await pages[pageNumber].setActive();
   console.log("Active page was set to: + pages[pageNumber].displayName);
   ```

Please find the reference below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/page-navigation